# Infinite pthread creating crashs application due to NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed

Tags: ios, ssl, pthreads, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I try to connect the internet to test the network in an application, if the network is connected or there's no connection, things go well. But there's a special situation, when the phone connected to wifi, but the wifi need to be logged in(that mean it will jump to a login page if the wifi is connected), and if I don't log in, things get weird: 
the application detected wifi, but it logs(by a network SDK):
`Update online config failed Error Domain=AVNetworkingErrorDomain Code=60 "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates"`
I understand this situation, for I didn't log in. But then, there'll be infinite error as `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)`, maybe 5 seconds per error.

And there will be a 99% cpu usage. When I use the instrument to see details, I find there's a thread named `_pthread_wqthread`creates infinite thread
[image: infinite call]

After some time, the app crashes.

And here's the device's running log:

```
Nov 28 02:49:19 XXXXXXX-iPhone bird[145] <Error>: failed uploading 1 items (273 字节) in com.apple.TextInput: <CKError 0x144e7f650: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some records"; partial errors: {
        documentContent/23EAA693-9E3F-4E21-BA02-08CF972FB90B:(com.apple.TextInput:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x144e676b0: "Network Failure" (4/-1202); "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “p18-ckdatabase.icloud.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.">
    }>
    Nov 28 02:49:24 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf SSLHostname]
Nov 28 02:49:24 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Warning>: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
Nov 28 02:49:38 XXXXXXX-iPhone configd[37] <Notice>: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Maintaining (__BUILTIN__)
Nov 28 02:49:38 XXXXXXX-iPhone configd[37] <Notice>: Captive: en0: Not probing "the wifi's name" (disabled by user)
Nov 28 02:49:38 XXXXXXX-iPhone configd[37] <Notice>: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Authenticated (__BUILTIN__)
Nov 28 02:49:43 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf SSLHostname]
Nov 28 02:49:43 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Warning>: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
Nov 28 02:49:54 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf SSLHostname]
Nov 28 02:49:54 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Warning>: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
Nov 28 02:50:08 XXXXXXX-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: 028115.172774 wlan0.A[4856] updateLinkQualityMetrics@1991:Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Nov 28 02:50:09 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf SSLHostname]
Nov 28 02:50:09 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Warning>: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
Nov 28 02:50:24 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf SSLHostname]
Nov 28 02:50:24 XXXXXXX-iPhone XXXXXXX[841] <Warning>: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
```

And I find -9843 means

> **errSSLHostNameMismatch  -9843**  The host name you connected with does
>   not match any of the host names allowed by the certificate. This is
>   commonly caused by an incorrect value for the kCFStreamSSLPeerName
>   property within the dictionary associated with the stream’s
>   kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings key. Available in OS X v10.4 and later.

More details, I used `AFNetworking` Library. Maybe this link is also helpful : [Crash in background NSURLSession "HTTPMessage::ensureParserFinished()"](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2334)

Comment: What do you mean "infinite pthread?" What makes it infinite? The error message you are reporting makes it sound like it has nothing to do with threading, it has to do with a certificate that doesn't match the site you're trying to connect to.

Comment: It seems because of the certificate mismatch, something continues to send message to connect, thus causes a lot of threads creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a (broken) captive portal situation, where the captive portal is responding to an HTTPS request with a response from a different domain.  Your code is apparently immediately retrying after a failure, causing massive CPU overhead.

You need to sit down with the list of NSURL error codes and make a list of the ones that are permanent—that is errors that are unlikely to go away in subsequent attempts, such as certificate errors on the server.  When your app sees any of those permanent errors, it should not immediately retry the request, regardless of reachability.